# What is this construction?

Tags: grammar

> I can't tell, but conclude that it was a good idea.

What is this construction?

Comment: The grammar Nazi in me wanted to change "conclude" to "concluded" (tense agreement), but edits sadly need to be at least 6 characters. OT: "tense agreement" is a good thing in grammar, a bad thing in international relations.

Comment: Why? The the sentence can be exapanded as _I can't tell, but I conclude that it was a good idea._ (And please don't use the term 'grammar Nazi'.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a sentence containing two independent clauses, coordinated by *but*. The second independent clause has a dependent clause as its object, and shows ellipsis in which the subject, *I*, can be recovered from the preceding clause.

Comment: You asked about the construction, not the meaning, but the meaning is _I don't know for sure, but my conclusion from all the available evidence is that it was a good idea._